# Published sources in maven local repository not visible in Android Studio IDE if proguard (R8) minification turned on

Tags: android, android-studio, intellij-idea, maven-publish, maven-repository

I want to publish some sources so that consumers of our closed-source library can see the documentation in their IDEs. I have this working so far:

```
def listOfPublicApiFiles = [
        '/com/example/app/MyClass.java',
        '/com/example/app/MyOtherClass.java',
]

task androidSourcesJar(type: Jar) {
    archiveClassifier.set('sources')
    include(listOfPublicApiFiles)
    includeEmptyDirs = false
    from android.sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs
}

publishing {
    publications {
        standardRelease(MavenPublication) {
            afterEvaluate {
                from components.standardRelease
                artifact androidSourcesJar
            }
            groupId = 'com.company'
            artifactId = "myartifact"
        }
    }
}
```

This works perfectly if `minifyEnabled false` is set, but as soon as I set `minifyEnabled true`, then no documentation at all appears in the IDE (by pressing F1, etc). Is this an IDE bug? The sources.jar is still there and appears to be linked properly. I don't see why it shouldn't work. I've tried making sure that these public API files are not minified at all by setting keep in proguard-rules, but it doesn't help, documentation in IDE is blank.

I'm using Android Studio Dolphin | 2021.3.1 Patch 1
Build #AI-213.7172.25.2113.9123335, built on September 30, 2022
Runtime version: 11.0.13+0-b1751.21-8125866 aarch64

but I have also tried on Electric Eel and Dolphin Android Studio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking into this problem for about a week, I finally found a reasonably simple solution:

Convert the files you want to publish documentation for to Kotlin. That way the documentation still is visible when `minifyEnabled true` is set, with the above publishing script.

I tried everything else that I could think of, but I'm not sure which part of the toolchain is breaking when the classes are Java. I assume it's either Gradle or IntelliJ.